# A differentiable homeomorphism that isn't a diffeomorphism?

Tags: differential-topology, diffeomorphism

From the book Introduction to Differentiable Topology by TH Brocker and K Janich.

> 1.7 Definition: A diffeomorphism is an invertible differentiable map

Below:

> A differentiable homeomorphism need not be a diffeomorphism, as is shown by the map $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \rightarrow x^3$.

I don't understand why this map is not a diffeomorphism. This appears differentiable ($x \rightarrow 3x^2$) and invertible $x \rightarrow x^{1/3}$. So I don't understand this example. I'm also confused because "differentiable homeomorphism" seem to equate differentiable and invertible. I must be misunderstanding a concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diffeomorphism requires both the function and its inverse are differentiable. But for $f(x)=x^3$, its inverse $f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$ fails to be differentiable at $x=0$, so $f$ is not a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Is this ill-captured in definition 1.7 or am I reading it wrong? 

1.7 Definition: A diffeomorphism is an invertible differentiable map

Comment: I think that textbook you are using had given further elaboration below the definition 1.7. 
"... This means in another words, $f$ is bijective and also $f^{-1}$ is differentiable."

Comment: Ah yes, that's right.